# Cannot run firebase locally. Illegal reflective access by io.netty.util.internal.ReflectionUtil

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cli

I cannot run a local version of my backend with firebase. I run `npm run dev` as i always have. But i get these errors. I have done nothing to change how this runs and it simply stopped a few days ago.

If i need to update any details please inform me and I can.

```
  emulators: Starting emulators: functions, firestore, database, hosting
i  firestore: Detected non-emulator Database export at /Users/davidjamesmitten/Dev_2020/apixel/functions
⚠  functions: The following emulators are not running, calls to these services from the Functions emulator will affect production: auth, pubsub
✔  functions: Using node@12 from host.
⚠  firestore: Did not find a Cloud Firestore rules file specified in a firebase.json config file.
⚠  firestore: The emulator will default to allowing all reads and writes. Learn more about this option: https://firebase.google.com/docs/emulator-suite/install_and_configure#security_rules_configuration.
i  firestore: Firestore Emulator logging to firestore-debug.log
i  database: Database Emulator logging to database-debug.log
events.js:291
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: write EPIPE
    at afterWriteDispatched (internal/stream_base_commons.js:156:25)
    at writeGeneric (internal/stream_base_commons.js:147:3)
    at Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:788:11)
    at Socket._write (net.js:800:8)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:403:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:387:5)
    at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:318:11)
    at Object.write (/Users/<user>/<dir>/<backend>/functions/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js:3234:36)
    at Object.onWatchStatusChange (/Users/<user>/<dir>/<backend>/functions/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js:86680:24)
    at /Users/<user>/<dir>/<backend>/functions/node_modules/typescript/lib/tsc.js:86895:125
Emitted 'error' event on Socket instance at:
    at errorOrDestroy (internal/streams/destroy.js:108:12)
    at onwriteError (_stream_writable.js:418:5)
    at onwrite (_stream_writable.js:445:5)
    at internal/streams/destroy.js:50:7
    at Socket.dummyDestroy [as _destroy] (internal/bootstrap/switches/is_main_thread.js:97:3)
    at Socket.destroy (internal/streams/destroy.js:38:8)
    at afterWriteDispatched (internal/stream_base_commons.js:156:17)
    at writeGeneric (internal/stream_base_commons.js:147:3)
    at Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:788:11)
    at Socket._write (net.js:800:8) {
  errno: 'EPIPE',
  code: 'EPIPE',
  syscall: 'write'
}
i  database: Importing data from /Users/<user>/<dir>/<backend>/functions/.runtimeconfig.json
i  emulators: Shutting down emulators.
i  functions: Stopping Functions Emulator
i  database: Stopping Database Emulator
i  firestore: Stopping Firestore Emulator
i  hub: Stopping emulator hub

Error: Error during database import.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! functions@ dev: `tsc -w | firebase functions:config:get > .runtimeconfig.json | firebase emulators:start --import=. --export-on-exit`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/<user>/.npm/_logs/2020-12-09T15_35_53_304Z-debug.log
```

Here are the logs:

```
**database-debug.log**

NING: An illegal reflective access operation has occurred
WARNING: Illegal reflective access by io.netty.util.internal.ReflectionUtil (file:/Users/davidjamesmitten/.cache/firebase/emulators/firebase-database-emulator-v4.7.1.jar) to field sun.nio.ch.SelectorImpl.selectedKeys
WARNING: Please consider reporting this to the maintainers of io.netty.util.internal.ReflectionUtil
WARNING: Use --illegal-access=warn to enable warnings of further illegal reflective access operations
WARNING: All illegal access operations will be denied in a future release
15:35:51.955 [NamespaceSystem-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-4] INFO akka.event.slf4j.Slf4jLogger - Slf4jLogger started
15:35:52.195 [main] INFO com.firebase.server.forge.App$ - Listening at localhost:9000
15:35:52.593 [Thread-0] INFO com.firebase.server.forge.App$ - Attempting graceful shutdown.
15:35:52.606 [Thread-0] INFO com.firebase.server.forge.App$ - Graceful shutdown complete.
```

```
**firestore-debug.log**

API endpoint: http://localhost:8080
If you are using a library that supports the FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST environment variable, run:

   export FIRESTORE_EMULATOR_HOST=localhost:8080

Dev App Server is now running.

*** shutting down gRPC server since JVM is shutting down
*** server shut down
```

**package.json**

```
  "name": "functions",
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "tslint --project tsconfig.json",
    "build": "tsc",
    "serve": "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='../apixel.json' tsc -w | firebase serve --only functions",
    "dev": "tsc -w | firebase functions:config:get > .runtimeconfig.json | firebase emulators:start --import=. --export-on-exit",
    "dev:public": "tsc -w | firebase emulators:start --import=. --export-on-exit",
    "shell": "npm run build && firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only functions",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log",
    "test": "ts-mocha --reporter spec --require @babel/register",
    "test:watch": "GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS='apixel-test.json' ts-mocha -w --reporter spec --require @babel/register --watch"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "12"
  },
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/cors": "^2.8.6",
    "@types/express": "^4.17.6",
    "chai": "^4.2.0",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "ejs": "^3.1.3",
    "express": "^4.17.1",
    "firebase": "^8.1.2",
    "firebase-admin": "^9.4.1",
    "firebase-functions": "^3.6.1",
    "firebase-tools": "^8.18.0",
    "jsdom": "^16.4.0",
    "node-fetch": "^2.6.1",
    "stripe": "^8.15.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.10.5",
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.5",
    "@babel/node": "^7.10.5",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/register": "^7.10.5",
    "firebase-functions-test": "^0.2.1",
    "mocha": "^8.0.1",
    "sinon": "^9.0.2",
    "supertest": "^4.0.2",
    "ts-mocha": "^7.0.0",
    "tslint": "^6.1.1",
    "typescript": "^3.8.0"
  },
  "private": true
}
```

Tried all sources I can think of to resolve this issue.

Comment: After making some research I've have found nothing about this or any similar at my end as you've already have done. In this case I'd recommend to open an issue directly in the repo of the [firebase tools](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues)

Comment: @davidmitten the error is probably described in `firebase-debug.log` not these other files you posted.

Comment: I'm getting same issue, please update here if you find a solution

Comment: I am facing the same issue, [3092](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/3092), [2992](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-tools/issues/2992) seems similar but i have not clue how to fix that

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error and this was because I was passing `--import=./firestore_export` as a flag but I did not have `firestore_export` which is a copy of my live dev database, probably you could solve this issue by removing the `--import` flag or by adding a `firestore_export`